# Gatsby build missing path prefix for images

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-image

After running `npm run deploy` (which is comprised of `"deploy": "gatsby build && gh-pages -d public -b master"`) it successfully deploys but the images are not there. I realize they are behind a `<noscript>` tag and are clearly missing the path prefix to work. Here is the repo: https://github.com/daletom/gatsby-universal and it deploys here: http://thedales.me/gatsby-universal/

I did add the path prefix in my gastby-config.js `pathPrefix: "/gatsby-universal",` and i tried running gatsby build followed by gatsby build --path-prefix then npm run build (and many other combos including path prefix)

This is the current image code showing up:

```
<noscript><picture><source srcset="/static/d83d4906eafa1a2c85b17c2f9569a2b7/b1f33/1.jpg 1x,
/static/d83d4906eafa1a2c85b17c2f9569a2b7/2a252/1.jpg 1.5x,
/static/d83d4906eafa1a2c85b17c2f9569a2b7/fe3b3/1.jpg 2x" /><img loading="lazy" width="500" height="500" srcset="/static/d83d4906eafa1a2c85b17c2f9569a2b7/b1f33/1.jpg 1x,
/static/d83d4906eafa1a2c85b17c2f9569a2b7/2a252/1.jpg 1.5x,
/static/d83d4906eafa1a2c85b17c2f9569a2b7/fe3b3/1.jpg 2x" src="/static/d83d4906eafa1a2c85b17c2f9569a2b7/b1f33/1.jpg" alt="React Context" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;opacity:1;width:100%;height:100%;object-fit:cover;object-position:center"/></picture></noscript>
```

If it were /gatsby-universal/static/image.jpg then it would actually work, which is why I believe the path prefix is messed up

Answer (score 4):

For me the issue seems to have been that the paths were cached. Running `gatsby clean` and then `gatsby build --prefix-paths` again fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out finally, apparently i should be doing --prefix-paths